# Grading table with question parts

Tags: exam

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
%\begingradingrange
\question[16]
\begin{parts}
\part[8] question 1
\part[8] question 2
\end{parts}
OR
\begin{parts}
\part[10] question 3
\part[6] question 4
\end{parts} 
%\endgradingrange

\end{questions}
Points Obtained:

\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{document}
```

I used the above commands to generate the grading table. I need to have the column in the grading table like the following

[image]

But currently I get this:

[image]

Help me to do this.

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible. You can only use gradetable for questions (by questionnumber of pagenumber), not for parts of a question. By the way, one question shouldn't have parts with the same name (a, b, ...) either your way with the two `parts` environments in one question, or this way `\begin{parts} \part[8] question 1 \part[8] question 2 \uplevel{OR} \setcounter{partno}{0} \part[10] question 3 \part[6] question 4 \end{parts} ` both give you duplicated labels.

Comment: But this way also giving the total number of points as 32 in the grading table whereas i need that is to show as nly 16@MaartenDhondt