# Exam class -- grade table for a single question?

Tags: exam

Let's say I have an `exam` with an open-response question worth ten points:

- 3 for the thesis
- 3 for the evidence supporting the thesis
- 3 for the explanation of how the evidence supports the thesis
- 1 for spelling, grammar, etc.

Is there a way to lay out that point allocation and create a grade table just for that question? (Specifically, is there a way to do this with grading ranges?) I want to make visible where the students' answers to the question succeed or fail.

## Unsatisfying options

- I can make a grading table manually, of course, but I'd prefer to do it programmatically if possible.
- I could list the criteria in a `parts` environment, which would also list the associated points, but that feels kludgy. (From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239545/grading-table-with-question-parts) I know that you can't make a grading table that breaks out the value of individual `part`s.)

## Update: What I'm working toward

Where I'm trying to get to would be something like this:

[image: rubric_mockup]

...where those criteria are `parts` of the question, so that they would be counted in a grading table for the whole test. The best idea I've been able to come up with is to create a special `rubricparts` environment to use instead of the normal `parts` environment; it would typeset the `items` in this tabular format instead of the usual list format. Of course, if there's a way to graft this onto the standard `parts` environment, so much the better.

This is as close as I can get to a MWE for this question. I know the lack of a MWE is penalized here, but I don't know how to start, or whether it can even be done.

## Update 2: MWE

I didn't initially add a MWE because I can't figure out how to start on this problem, so, by definition, anything that I would put forward doesn't work. But I can add a MWE that compiles, even though it doesn't include any attempt to do what I want:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        
        \question How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
        
        \begin{parts}
            
            \part [3] Thesis
            \part [3] Evidence
            \part [3] Analysis
            \part [1] Mechanics
        
        \end{parts}
        
    
    \end{questions}
    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make a sketch of what the expected result should look like?

Comment: @caverac I don't know how helpful it'll be, because it's not a real MWE, but I added a mock-up.

Comment: So what you want is to type the scores for each question and then show them in this format? My apologies, don't mean to sound thick, it is just that I'm not familiar with this type of tests

Comment: @caverac Right. So if I typed in `\part [3] Thesis \part [3] Evidence`, etc., it would generate this table.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Added, with ambivalence.

Comment: Do you want a table for each question? Or all of them at the end?

Comment: Ideally, one for each question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{
 /question/.is family, /question,
 default/.style = {thesis = 3, evidence = 3, analysis = 3, mechanics = 1},
 thesis/.estore in = \scoreThesis,
 evidence/.estore in = \scoreEvidence,
 analysis/.estore in = \scoreAnalysis,
 mechanics/.estore in = \scoreMechanics,
}

\newcommand\addquestion[2][]{%
 \pgfkeys{/question, default, #1}%

 % Problem
 \textcolor{blue}{#2} % Format for the question

 % Scores
 \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
     Criterion & Thesis & Evidence & Analysis & Mechanics \\ \hline 
     Points & \scoreThesis & \scoreEvidence & \scoreAnalysis & \scoreMechanics \\ \hline
     Score & & & & \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \addquestion[thesis = 2, evidence = 2, analysis = 2, mechanics = 4]
{How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?}

\item \addquestion[]
{How many boards could the mongols hoard if the mongol hordes got bored?}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]